Dispense applied to Faucet will affect the safety of my household?
I have been using an assistant.command.OkGoogle action to automate filling some standard vessels with water. It's a bit annoying, because it keeps asking me if I can't reach the faucet, making it a 2-step process and very slow.
I was trying to update the automation to use device.command.Dispense, but when I validate, it tells me:
[Dispense] applied to [Faucet - Kitchen] could impact the safety, security, and/or privacy of your household.
I don't understand how that can be the case.
I have a Delta faucet with the VoiceIQ module
Expected:
Dispense action allows me to dispense the configured amount of water from my faucet
Actual:
Automation will not validate because Dispense applied to the Faucet could impact safety, security, and/or privacy
